# Advise that the question was edited

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification that question has been edited or re-tagged while answering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/notification-that-question-has-been-edited-or-re-tagged-while-answering)

So, there I was answering a question for which no language was specified. Once I finish writing and testing it, and post the answer, I learn the question was edited while I was doing that, and a (different) language was specified.

So, could we please get warned when the question is edited?

**EDIT**

While a language tag is an uncommon -- not rare -- situation, and one which you may prepare yourself against if the question doesn't look like an algorithm one, it is a **common** situation for updates to the question be posted that complement it with useful information in the few minutes right after it was made. If one is used to answering recently asked questions, like I am, we see it often.

Now, there exists a notification that other answers have been posted. Ego-wise, that's useful. But it is much more useful, as far as making a good answer, to be notified the question was modified. It is because of that that I'm asking for this feature.

- PS: "Common", here, means "I got used to see it happen".

Comment: Post a link to the question / your answer.

Comment: Not really a dup, seeing as how in Daniel's case the answer hadn't been posted yet. In practice though, i think #2322 would be more useful - as Ian notes, it's best to just avoid answering language-specific questions where no language is specified.

Comment: @Brad what's the relevance of that particular question/answer? I was just illustrating a situation that happens often to me. I could have made an hypothetical example instead.

Comment: @cletus No, it is not, as @Shog9 indicated, a dup. As for the usefulness, I'm complementing.

Answer (score 3):

You should be wary of answer questions that specify no language and are not tagged as <kbd>language-agnostic</kbd>. I fear your request is somewhat limited to very rare cases where such information creates a drastic change in the question.

Comment: No one -- as in, very few people, uses the language-agnostic tag, but this isn't really relevant. I usually target algorithms and newbies. In both cases there's often edits to the question, providing information -- often constraints -- the person didn't think of including in the original question, or clarifying some point people are interpreting incorrectly.

Comment: Language tags are just one case, I've seen this several times myself, which leads to some needless editing on my part which could have been avoided had I known the question was edited.