# Notification that question has been edited or re-tagged while answering

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, edits, notifications

Related to [Notify us when the question has been edited after posting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2322/notify-us-when-the-question-has-been-edited-after-posting-an-answer)

I believe a notification that a question has been edited or re-tagged would be very useful. If I am in the middle of answering a question that is simultaneously edited, I might like to know whether the parameters have been redefined.

For example, I was in the middle of answering [How to determine that there is date in the string or not with different date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793558/regex-for-date) when the question was significantly changed. The OP rolled those changes back and asked a new question (kudos to him), but not all users would be so gracious.

Comment: I think I just saw this on SO (a little `this has been edited` notification) and it is a great feature. Well done!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I completely agree. This has happened so many times... I go through a long process of answering the question... only to submit it and see that the question has been edited to go in a completely different direction.

The solution you present would work quite well. I think retagging should be left alone, though. So often someone will just retag it to categorize it better - not to change the meaning of the question.

Comment: valid point about tags -- it would be much more advantageous to notify if a question is edited.

Comment: Welcome to the 1k club @George. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Edit notifications for a post are now delivered via web sockets.  I'm sure there will be a few tweaks as we learn how these new notifications impact usability, however, the framework for this is now in place.