# What does it mean when no one will answer or comment on a bounty?

Tags: discussion, participation

Honestly, I thought there would be some feedback from this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/notification-that-question-has-been-edited-or-re-tagged-while-answering) *(other than the obvious 5 votes that covered my bounty)*. So, from that I would gather that the idea didn't totally suck. Based on the reception so far I wondered though if maybe my question was unclear.

Well, I know that the meta community wouldn't let me get away with an unclear question. There would ensue a small slurry of `more information/examples please`. I know what down-votes mean on meta. What does it mean when no one is even commenting on a question regarding a feature request?

If the subject matter is not disagreeable and would at least solicit the up-votes to cover the bounty, what makes my question unengaging? We have had question on how to gain up-votes (write better questions to provide clear and concise guidelines for a problem), but what about questions on meta to solicit engaging participation?

The other thing I thought about why I wouldn't be getting the views and comments is because I am only garnering a fraction of the audience that would benefit from a feature (in my opinion, of course). So, then I wondered if it would be beneficial for a list of feature requests posted on meta to be displayed on the home page of SOFU. Somewhere in the margin and possibly only feature requests that have had bounties put on them - kinda like paying for premium advertisement space. Oh well...you can start slagging me for beginning to ramble.

Comment: +1 for your last idea. More meta integration on the main sites would be very cool.

Comment: @Earlz, yeah it kinda hit me that there are probably a large number of viewers that don't know to vote on feature requests on meta. Cross-marketing the sites.

Comment: Yay! Bounty! I answered your question.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback in the answers. With my first feature-request, I just wasn't sure how to interpret the (lack of) feedback. I'm still learning.

Comment: Meta can take quite a lot of learning :-) When in doubt just post pictures of waffles with freehand circles drawn around them. You can't lose then!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I know what down-votes mean on meta.
>   What does it mean when no one is even
>   commenting on a question regarding a
>   feature request?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but when I see:

- a question like yours
- describing a specific situation
- proposing a new feature
- with a clear indication of why that feature is beneficial
- with 10 upvotes
- and no comments / answers

I'd say that means: you have made a valid point, people agree with you, and hopefully you'll see one (very short) answer from Jeff and a `[status-completed]` tag added to your question...

Answer (score 3):

The votes were the feedback.  I gave you an upvote because I thought it was a good idea, but didn't have anything worth putting in an answer.