# Add other types of notifications when answering the question

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, notifications

There is already [similar request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/notification-that-question-has-been-edited-or-re-tagged-while-answering) for notifications about edits in question when we are writing answers. I would like to extend this request to notification that user has already deleted the question. Generally it would be nice to be notified about any changes to the content or the state of the question in the same way we are notified about new answers.

Edit:

I found yesterday that notification about deletion has been already added. Am I right?

Comment: +1, good call. That's caught me a couple of times, and, personally, I'd consider 'deletion' to be a **major** edit.

Comment: Even if owner deleted the post, 10k+ users can still edit it, right?

Comment: @YOU: Yes they can but it was not point of this feature request. I asked for notification (orange bar in the top) when user deletes the question while you are typing the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This already exists -- if the question is closed, deleted, migrated etc while you are composing an answer, this is what you'll see.

[image]

Just substitute **deleted** with closed. This ping happens every 45 seconds as you compose an answer.