# Notifying that the question or an answer has been edited while viewing page

Tags: feature-request, notifications, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification that question has been edited or re-tagged while answering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/notification-that-question-has-been-edited-or-re-tagged-while-answering)

Currently, if one is writing an answer to a question and someone else posts an answer, we get a banner notification on top. I'm not sure, but I think that the banner appears if you are vieweing the page even if not actively typing an answer (it may be that this only occurs if there has been *some* writing done in the answer box).

If an answer previously posted is edited while you are writing an answer (or while viewing), however, it seems that one does *not* get a notification. Is there any chance of adding such a notification (or changing the "an answer has been posted" banner to "an answer has been posted or modified")? Or would it cost too many resources to keep track of edits as well as new answers?

Comment: We actually don't keep track of edits that occur within a 5 minute window of the initial posting. Are you talking about notifications for *those* edits, or merely notifications for regular edits that show up in the post's revision history?

Comment: @Cody: Regular edits that show up in the history. Say it's been a while since the answer/question was posted/last edited. It gets edited *while* I'm looking at the page (or while I'm writing an answer). Just like I would get a banner saying "A new answer has been posted", getting a notification saying "An answer has been edited" or "The question has been edited", which would alert me to this.

Comment: Fair enough, although in my experience that's fairly rare. The only time you really see a lot of game-changing edits is when the question/answer are *first* posted, largely a symptom of the "Fastest Gun In The West" problem. But an interesting proposal nevertheless.