# When writing an answer, notify that comments have been posted or edits have been made

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Notification that question has been edited or re-tagged while answering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49248/notification-that-question-has-been-edited-or-re-tagged-while-answering)
>   [Micro-refinement to notifications for comments of others posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts)

Currently, if an answer is posted while you're writing one of your own, you get a big notification about it. I think it would be useful for the concept to extend to comments and edits. Maybe the question originally had two interpretations/solutions and your answer covered both, but a comment or edit has ruled out one of them. Maybe an assumption you were making has been squashed, or something someone said has provoked an additional insight.

Of course, in most cases comments probably aren't worth the Bar Of Page-Sliding<sup>TM</sup>, and most edits are corrective rather than informative. Still, the use cases seem reasonable.

Comment: You don't get notified when there are new comments on the page or when someone else has posted an edit before you (and you're in the process of editing)?

Comment: @casperOne I don't get notifications when the question is edited or a comment is posted while I'm writing my answer; I believe this is what he's referring to.

Comment: When this happens, the entire left column of the page shifts down to show the "An edit has been made to this post" box, which could be an edit to an answer or to the question. I think the same shifting happens for comments too, so the "Show X more comments" box has room.